# $\pi$ is isomorphism from one Peano system $(N, S, e)$ to another $(N', S', e')$, then $\pi^{-1}$ is isomorphism from $(N', S', e')$ to $(N, S, e)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, peano-axioms

This is an exercise from Cunningham's book "Set Theory: A First Course".

**Theorem:** Let $(N, S, e)$ and $(N', S', e')$ be Peano systems. Let $\pi$ be an isomorphism from $(N, S, e)$ onto $(N', S', e')$. Prove that $\pi^{-1}$ is thus an isomorphism from $(N', S', e')$ onto $(N, S, e)$.

**Definition:** Isomorphism $\pi$ is the following bijection
$$
\pi = 
\begin{cases}
\pi(e) = e' \\
(\forall x \in N)\pi(S(x)) = S'(\pi(x))
\end{cases} 
$$
*Proof:* Let $(N, S, e)$ and $(N', S', e')$ be Peano systems. Let $\pi$ be an isomorphism from $(N, S, e)$ onto
$(N', S', e')$. $\pi$ is a bijection, so is $\pi^{-1}$. To prove that $\pi^{-1}\colon N'\to N$ is an isomorphism we have to show
that:
$$
\pi^{-1} = 
\begin{cases}
\pi^{-1}(e') = e \\
(\forall x \in N')(\pi^{-1}(S'(x)) = S(\pi^{-1}(x)))
\end{cases} 
$$

Since $\pi(e)=e'$ then $\pi^{-1}(e') = e$. Now we prove the second statement by induction.
Consider a set $A = \{y \in N': \pi^{-1}(S'(y)) = S(\pi^{-1}(y)))\}$, prove that it is closed under
$S'$. First show that $e'\in A$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\pi(S(e)) &= S'(\pi(e)) &\text{def. of $\pi$} \\
\pi(e) &= e' \\
\pi^{-1}(e') &= e \\
\pi^{-1}(S'(e')) &= S(\pi^{-1}(e')) \\
e' &\in A
\end{align*}
$$
For induction hypothesis assume $y \in A$, therefore $\pi^{-1}(S'(y)) = S(\pi^{-1}(y))$. Show that $S'(y)$ is also in $A$ by proving that $\pi^{-1}(S'(S'(y))) = S(\pi^{-1}(S'(y)))$ holds. Since $y \in N'$ and $\pi^{-1}:N' \to N$ is bijection, then there exists unique $x \in N$ such that $x = \pi^{-1}(y)$
$$
\begin{align*} 
(\forall x \in N)(\pi(S(x)) &= S'(\pi(x))) &\text{def. of $\pi$}\\
S(x) &\in N \\
\pi(S(S(x)) &= S'(\pi(S(x)))) &\text{from def. of $\pi$} \\
\pi(S(x) &= S'(\pi(x))) &\text{from def. of $\pi$} \\
\pi(S(S(x)) &= S'(S'(\pi(x))) \\
\pi^{-1}(S'(S'(\pi(x)))) &= S(S(x)) \\
\pi^{-1}(S'(S'(\pi(\pi^{-1}(y))))) &= S(S(\pi^{-1}(y)))) &\text{replacing $x$ with $\pi^{-1}(y)$}\\
\pi^{-1}(S'(S'(y)))) &= S(S(\pi^{-1}(y))) \\
\pi^{-1}(S'(S'(y)))) &= S(\pi^{-1}(S'(y))) &\text{by Induction Hypothesis}\\
S'(y) &\in A \\
\text{The set $A$ is closed under $S'$, hence $A=N'$.} \\
(\forall x \in N')(\pi^{-1}(S'(x)) &= S(\pi^{-1}(x))) 
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore $\pi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $(N', S', e')$ onto $(N, S, e).\qquad\square$

Even though the derivation above seems valid to me it feels too "straight forward", therefore my questions are: is the proof valid and whether more "elegant" solution exists. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction is not needed here.

For $x \in N'$, let $y = \pi^{-1}(x)$, so $x = \pi(y)$. Since $\pi$ is an isomorphism $$S'(x) = S'(\pi(y)) = \pi(S(y))$$ and $$\pi^{-1}(S'(x)) = S(y) = S (\pi^{-1}(x))$$
as required.

This is a simple theorem. One would expect its proof to be straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see how I needlessly overcomplicated things here.

Comment: Overcomplicating things is something we've all done. As a general rule, proving invertible algebraic homomorphisms have homomorphic inverses is simple, always following this same pattern. Conversely, for invertible topologic homomorphisms, you have to specifically assume the inverse is also a topologic homomorphism when defining an isomorphism.